# Very simple if else check in Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

This is likely embarrassingly easy but I'm new and I've been beating my head against the wall on this for a while now. What I am attempting to do is basically a modified version of the "Hello App Maker!" If else test.

The necessary info I have the following widgets attached to the appropriate data sources:

> - Dropdown widget called `source_name` (string - list)
> - Label widget I've called `name` (string)
> - Text Box widget called `qty_duration` (number)
> - Label widget I've called `hours` (number)

I have a dropdown widget called `source_name` with 5 options. On selection I have the value appear in a label widget I've called `name`. If the option selected from the drop down widget is ever `LABOUR` I am trying to then have the value of a Text Box widget called `qty_duration` appear in a label widget I've called `hours`

On the `source_name` dropdown event - `onValueChange` I have the following code:

```
// Define variables for the input and output widgets
var nameWidget = app.pages.Apex_job_details.descendants.name;
var outputWidget = app.pages.Apex_job_details.descendants.hours;
var techhours = app.pages.Apex_job_details.descendants.qty_duration;
var nothing = 0;


// If a name is LABOUR, add the qty to the output widget Else output 0.
if (nameWidget == 'LABOUR') {
  outputWidget.text = techhours;
} else {
  outputWidget = nothing;
}
```

It's not giving me any errors, but it's also not outputting to the `hours` label. If I edit the code as follows just to muck with it:

```
// Define variables for the input and output widgets
var nameWidget = app.pages.Apex_job_details.descendants.name;
var outputWidget = app.pages.Apex_job_details.descendants.hours;
var techhours = app.pages.Apex_job_details.descendants.qty_duration;
var nothing = 0;

// If a name is LABOUR, add the qty to the output widget Else output 0.
if (nameWidget == 'LABOUR') {
  outputWidget.text = techhours;
} else {
  outputWidget.text = nothing;
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Techhours is an input widget, therefore to get to it's value you need to use `app.pages.Apex_job_details.descendants.qty_duration.value`.

Comment: It's just telling me... Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at Apex_job_details.Panel1.Panel5.Table1.Table1Body.Table1Row.Panel6.name_source.onValueChange:4:69

Comment: Is this textbox widget inside a table row also? If so that is the cause of all your problems then, because table row widgets have a widget name, but they cannot be referenced by an absolute reference like you are doing, because the widget with that same name would be at row index 0, row index 1, etc. What is techhours actually pointing to? If it is a field value in your datasource you are much better off using `widget.datasource.item.YourField` when referencing anything in table row.

Comment: Yes it's in a table, and yes that make sense. - So it should read more along the lines of the following:  ` // Define variables for the input and output widgets
var nameWidget = app.pages.Apex_job_details.descendants.name;
var outputWidget = widget.datasource.item.hours;
var techhours = widget.datasource.item.qty_duration;
var nothing = 0;


// If a name is LABOUR, add the qty to the output widget Else output 0.
if (nameWidget == 'LABOUR') {
  outputWidget.value = techhours.value;
} else {
  outputWidget.value = nothing.value;
} `

Comment: Posted a possible code edit as an answer. That is based on the assumption however that all your labels and inputs are inside a table row.

Comment: That is awesome. It works perfectly and it's simple. I understand what you did  and I can use it on a bunch of other stuff that will make my life so much simpler in the future. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all labels and input widgets are inside a table row you will want to adjust your code as follows:

```
var tablerow = widget.parent;
var nameWidget = tablerow.descendants.name.text;
var outputWidget = tablerow.descendants.hours;
var techhours = tablerow.descendants.qty_duration.value;

if(nameWidget === 'LABOUR') {
  outputWidget.text = techhours;
} else {
  outputWidget.text = null;
}
```

By using widget.parent in the onValueChange event of the dropdown you will automatically reference the table row and then by using descendants you are referencing only the descendants of that table row. This will bridge the error by using an absolute reference when using table rows. If it still doesn't work let me know.